# cfmail not sending to external address

Tags: email, coldfusion, cfmail

I have a new web server that I am testing before turning it on live. I have run into a cfmail issue. The server is
Windows 2008 R2, 64Gig ram, 64-bit, IIS 7.5, Coldfusion 9.0.2 multi server, clustering 2 CF instances (my 1st time clustering), JDK1.7.0_71

cfmail is not sending email to recipients outside of our domain/work domain. The 1st cfmail tag below sends the email but the 2nd one does not. This is what I see when trying to send via the 2nd  tag with external recipient email address domain

- no errors on the page I run in the browser
- email is not received at me@home.com (syntax is correct)
- attempt #2 shows up in mail/Undelivr folder
- mail.log has this error
  "Error","scheduler-3","01/15/15","10:13:27",,"javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;   nested exception is:  com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay
- application.log - no error
- exception.log has same error in addition to stack trace
- server.log no error

The same .cfm file I am testing with works fine on all of our other CF servers so I do not think it is the mail server configured in the CF admin. Any help is appreciated

```
<cfmail to="me@**work**.com" from="someone@work.com" subject="test" type="html">


<cfmail to="me@**home**.com" from="someone@work.com" subject="test" type="html">
```

Comment: Your network or corporate firewall might be blocking it. Check with your N/w team.

Comment: I turned off the Windows Firewll and that did not help. I will check with corporate. Thanks for the suggestion. Anit.

Comment: This is almost certainly an SMTP issue and not ColdFusion. If ColdFusion thought that the email address were invalid, it would raise an error rather than trying to send it. My guess is that the SMTP server is not configured to relay from this particular CF server.

Comment: David, you were right. We had to add the IP for the new web server to our mail relay server. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was our mail relay server did not have the IP of the new web server. After adding the IP of the new web server it worked just fine.

Thanks David!